# Replace a "Web page not available" Error in WebView with something less ugly? (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, webview

I have a WebView Activity that sometimes doesn't load up properly due to a disconnected or poor WIFI/DATA connection. I imagine this is more than likely to happen in the real world once my app is deployed. My question is how can I replace this ugly error with something more pretty?

Also, do you have any other tips for getting my WebView Activity to NOT resemble a browser?
For example, instead of a white screen showing up while the WebView is loading, how can I show a loading icon during this moment?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a page is not found the page returns a 404 error, what you need to do is handle it.

This can be done by setting a `WebViewClient` and overriding `onReceivedError` method.

You can Try something like this :

```
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
 wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
             //handle the 404
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }
 });
```

Comment: because you need to actually capture it, this code only sets event for any error.